# I have a method which returns class type in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and C# and i have this below question which i do not know what to call it as

I have a method as

```
public Account GetAccountDetails(){ //where Account is a class

    return new Account{
        text = GetNameOfAccount;
        length = GetLengthOfAccountNumber;

    };
}//end of method
```

I knew that i would be able to get the properties and fields from the above method and i can use it. But, what do you call the above method as some object initializers or anonymous type? How is it useful than explicitly defining an object for Account class and using the object for accessing the methods?

Comment: Can you replace "some properties and other fields are here" with the actual code, and format your code so it's readable?  Also, I'm not sure what your actual question is.  Please clarify.

Comment: This question is too vague, but object initializers are really just short hand, but they are dangerous because you may not fully initialize something

Comment: @johnny5 -- Eh, even without object initializers, you may not fully init something.  I don't see why using them makes a difference in that respect.

Comment: What does this mean: "But, what do you call the above method as some object initializers or anonymous type?"  And I don't see any methods there, so what do you mean by "How is it useful than explicitly defining an object for Account class and using the object for **accessing the methods**?"

Comment: I saw that code and couldn't understand what it means fully.In the above code i have the method as GetAccountDetails and it returns a class type. In that code what i couldn't understand was return new <class> {}; . My question was what does this kind of method which returns class type in c# known as?

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking... Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern?

Comment: @rory.ap that is true,  I really should have mentioned there bigger pit fall which that they could cause you to accidently leak resouces mention in [phil haacked blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2013/01/11/hidden-pitfalls-with-object-initializers.aspx/)

Comment: @johnny5 -- Wow, *very* interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the method you mentioned is like a ordering the `Set Menu of McDonald`.

Imagine if you are working in McDonald and large number of people stand in front of you.

If Set Menu is not exist, every people order buger and coke and potato or other menu separately. It test your brain.

but in real world, some people order Set menu and some people order separately.
so you can memory them more efficiently.

It is also express to code.

```cs
public Order getSetA() {
    return new Order {
        Buger = Menu.CheeseBugger;
        Drink = Menu.Coke;
        SideMenu = Menu.Potato;
    };
}


public Order getSetB() {
    return new Order {
        Buger = Menu.BigMac;
        Drink = Menu.Water;
        SideMenu = Menu.Pickle;
    };
}

Order order = new Order();
RandomBugerForToday(out order.Buger);
RandomDrinkForToday(out order.Drink);
order.SideMenu = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for a very good  explanation with a real world example. I got the answer :)